# Youtube API Retrieve Live Stream Game Title

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to retrieve the game title of a live stream using the Youtube Api.

[image]

I am currently using the

[Videos:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) api but it doesn't seem to return this information. It does give me some topic ids but they do not represent specific games.

Is this information possible to get through the API?

Thank You

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63578839/how-to-retrieve-game-title-bound-to-video) already has an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Check this response I think it has all you need.
It is not video list API it is streaming API.

```json
"title": string is what you need.
{
  "kind": "youtube#liveStream",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": string,
  "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": datetime,
    "channelId": string,
    "title": string,
    "description": string,
    "isDefaultStream": boolean
  },
  "cdn": {
    "format": string,
    "ingestionType": string,
    "ingestionInfo": {
      "streamName": string,
      "ingestionAddress": string,
      "backupIngestionAddress": string
    },
    "resolution": string,
    "frameRate": string
  },
  "status": {
    "streamStatus": string,
    "healthStatus": {
      "status": string,
      "lastUpdateTimeSeconds": unsigned long,
      "configurationIssues": [
        {
          "type": string,
          "severity": string,
          "reason": string,
          "description": string
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "contentDetails": {
    "closedCaptionsIngestionUrl": string,
    "isReusable": boolean
  }
}
```

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams

Comment: I thought so too when I was researching the api docs but I couldn't find that information in the response.

Comment: Please see the link and run it with your developer link It is stream title.

Comment: Can you provide a video id with which we can verify your answer?

Answer (score -2):

This is the sample response of the [Video:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22Ks-_Mh1QhMc%22%7D)

```json
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"/zEUr9vFiEhEIvxHhZu87B-iG4CM\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"\"",
   "id": "Ks-_Mh1QhMc",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2012-10-01T15:27:35.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCAuUUnT6oDeKwE6v1NGQxug",
    "title": "Your body language may shape who you are | Amy Cuddy",
    "description": "Body language affects how others see us, but it may also change how we see ourselves. Social psychologist Amy Cuddy argues that \"power posing\" -- standing in a posture of confidence, even when we don't feel confident -- can boost feelings of confidence, and might have an impact on our chances for success. (Note: Some of the findings presented in this talk have been referenced in an ongoing debate among social scientists about robustness and reproducibility. Read Amy Cuddy's response here: http://ideas.ted.com/inside-the-debate-about-power-posing-a-q-a-with-amy-cuddy/)\n\nGet TED Talks recommended just for you! Learn more at https://www.ted.com/signup.\n\nThe TED Talks channel features the best talks and performances from the TED Conference, where the world's leading thinkers and doers give the talk of their lives in 18 minutes (or less). Look for talks on Technology, Entertainment and Design -- plus science, business, global issues, the arts and more.\n\nFollow TED on Twitter: http://www.twitter.com/TEDTalks\nLike TED on Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/TED\n\nSubscribe to our channel: https://www.youtube.com/TED",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Ks-_Mh1QhMc/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Ks-_Mh1QhMc/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Ks-_Mh1QhMc/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Ks-_Mh1QhMc/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     },
     "maxres": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Ks-_Mh1QhMc/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 720
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "TED",
    "tags": [
     "Amy Cuddy",
     "TED",
     "TEDTalk",
     "TEDTalks",
     "TED Talk",
     "TED Talks",
     "TEDGlobal",
     "brain",
     "business",
     "psychology",
     "self",
     "success"
    ],
    "categoryId": "22",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
    "defaultLanguage": "en",
    "localized": {
     "title": "Your body language may shape who you are | Amy Cuddy",
     "description": "Body language affects how others see us, but it may also change how we see ourselves. Social psychologist Amy Cuddy argues that \"power posing\" -- standing in a posture of confidence, even when we don't feel confident -- can boost feelings of confidence, and might have an impact on our chances for success. (Note: Some of the findings presented in this talk have been referenced in an ongoing debate among social scientists about robustness and reproducibility. Read Amy Cuddy's response here: http://ideas.ted.com/inside-the-debate-about-power-posing-a-q-a-with-amy-cuddy/)\n\nGet TED Talks recommended just for you! Learn more at https://www.ted.com/signup.\n\nThe TED Talks channel features the best talks and performances from the TED Conference, where the world's leading thinkers and doers give the talk of their lives in 18 minutes (or less). Look for talks on Technology, Entertainment and Design -- plus science, business, global issues, the arts and more.\n\nFollow TED on Twitter: http://www.twitter.com/TEDTalks\nLike TED on Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/TED\n\nSubscribe to our channel: https://www.youtube.com/TED"
    },
    "defaultAudioLanguage": "en"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT21M3S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "hd",
    "caption": "true",
    "licensedContent": true,
    "projection": "rectangular"
   },
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "17328644",
    "likeCount": "241869",
    "dislikeCount": "4823",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "7741"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

you can get that information from the title and form localized.title

I hope language sdk's support this.

Below is the screenshot image for the title

[image: Screenshot image to verify title]

Comment: Where are you seeing this information? I don't see the correct information under title?

Comment: Its there In Developer Docs. & i will add screenshots as proof

Comment: That is not the title I am looking for. It is a separate field inside the description. https://www.screencast.com/t/Pka3vzUu