# How to retrieve game title bound to video

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Does anyone know how to get the game title assigned to video via the Youtube API?

Game title screenshot from YT web.  Here I need to get the `Call of Duty` game from this video:

[image]

Documentation doesn't have any information regarding game title in the video resource: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos

API query with the broadest content settings returns this:

```json
{
"kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
"etag": "0KGf7UH0NGSsvuQJqAEX4e1mE00",
"items": [
    {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "etag": "atR4AXswOz04SvjBEFuPTUpgEKo",
        "id": "Tn2TgqkrCng",
        "snippet": {
            "publishedAt": "2016-09-23T16:31:31Z",
            "channelId": "UCv2IxyoJetx3b3nPbHJbx3g",
            "title": "Batman: The Telltale Games Series [#7][Epizod 2 FINAŁ]",
            "description": "Wrzućcie like'a na facebooku: ",
            "thumbnails": {
                "default": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Tn2TgqkrCng/default.jpg",
                    "width": 120,
                    "height": 90
                },
                "medium": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Tn2TgqkrCng/mqdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 320,
                    "height": 180
                },
                "high": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Tn2TgqkrCng/hqdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 480,
                    "height": 360
                },
                "standard": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Tn2TgqkrCng/sddefault.jpg",
                    "width": 640,
                    "height": 480
                },
                "maxres": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Tn2TgqkrCng/maxresdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 1280,
                    "height": 720
                }
            },
            "channelTitle": "Tivolt",
            "tags": [
                "tivolt",
                "let's play",
                "zagrajmy w",
                "gameplay",
                "gry",
                "zagrajmy",
                "vlog",
                "fajne",
                "gta",
                "batman",
                "telltale"
            ],
            "categoryId": "20",
            "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
            "localized": {
                "title": "Batman: The Telltale Games Series [#7][Epizod 2 FINAŁ]",
                "description": "Wrzućcie like'a na facebooku: "
            },
            "defaultAudioLanguage": "pl"
        },
        "status": {
            "uploadStatus": "processed",
            "privacyStatus": "public",
            "license": "youtube",
            "embeddable": true,
            "publicStatsViewable": true,
            "madeForKids": false
        },
        "statistics": {
            "viewCount": "33035",
            "likeCount": "1681",
            "dislikeCount": "23",
            "favoriteCount": "0",
            "commentCount": "131"
        },
        "player": {
            "embedHtml": "<iframe width=\"480\" height=\"270\" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/Tn2TgqkrCng\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"
        },
        "topicDetails": {
            "relevantTopicIds": [
                "/m/02vxn",
                "/m/025zzc",
                "/m/0403l3g"
            ],
            "topicCategories": [
                "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_game",
                "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film",
                "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-playing_video_game"
            ]
        },
        "recordingDetails": {}
    }
],
"pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 1
}
}
```

As you can see, there is no info about game title. Has anyone struggled with this and knows the way how to do it?

Someone has already posted the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58034959/youtube-api-retrieve-live-stream-game-title), but it looks like everyone misunderstood him, there is no correct answer and I have no rep to comment in this thread.

Comment: Well, what is your API call and what is the video ID? Your results do not match so I think you requested a different video.

Comment: Screenshot and API response are from different video. That was just an example. I want to retrieve information in response body like: gameId: 123. This one property is missing in body pasted above, documentation doesn't say anything about that and gathering this data is important to me.

Comment: What makes you think the API response will have 'gameId'?

Comment: It's just business need... I know that this data isn't available officially and I'm looking for workaround. Youtube website displays this, so why it's not returned via API?

Comment: @kbernatjanusziewicz because YouTube Data API does not work as YouTube works - it has its own limitations. If such data is not shown in the reponse of the api, then, it might be the metadata of the video itself and not available through YouTube API.

Answer (score 2):

One more time YouTube Data API v3 doesn't provide a basic feature.

I recommend you to try out my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/commit/130e7f7e27dcfeefbf5621717d9636c114d66a6d) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com). Indeed by fetching https://yt.lemnoslife.com/videos?part=activity&id=VIDEO_ID, you will get the activity you are looking for in `item["activity"]["name"]`.

With the video id [`V6z0qF54RZ4`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6z0qF54RZ4) you would get:

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
    "etag": "NotImplemented",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "NotImplemented",
            "id": "V6z0qF54RZ4",
            "activity": {
                "name": "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive",
                "year": "2012",
                "thumbnails": [
                    {
                        "url": "https:\/\/yt3.ggpht.com\/BcAQ-GIrhOTxPRUkDoyXdbaRMUsU3k1yRTDgMvXsMa18XAPZedPQA9N8I5VL7eNDWL1ppBTmfQ=s100-w72-h100-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-nd-rj",
                        "width": 72,
                        "height": 100
                    },
                    {
                        "url": "https:\/\/yt3.ggpht.com\/BcAQ-GIrhOTxPRUkDoyXdbaRMUsU3k1yRTDgMvXsMa18XAPZedPQA9N8I5VL7eNDWL1ppBTmfQ=s200-w144-h200-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-nd-rj",
                        "width": 144,
                        "height": 200
                    }
                ],
                "channelId": "UC279mtSpGdNDRVE_NqSPofA"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```